# Lightning Sync - Match Events on Custom Email Field

Tags: apex, lightning, sync

We are looking to sync over google calendar events into Salesforce. We'd like these events to match to contacts and link, however the email addresses of our users in GSuite correspond to a custom email field, NOT the standard contact email field.

1) Is there a way to set Lightning Sync to match on a different field other than standard email?
2) Is there a way to access what data is coming in on the sync? For example, if we could see in the event the emails of the attendees, we could write a trigger to custom match these and link them.

Thanks
George